# Can I use OLS to analyse Cross-sectional data?

Tags: least-squares

I am conducting analysis of cross-sectional data for research purpose, so will it be wise to employ OLS to analyse cross-sectional data and find out the corresponding coefficients of those variables in such process, or there is any other preferable way to analyse this. Perhaps, it is not pooled cross-sectional data which is associated time but it is taken only in one single time, so a bit confused of this thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OLS is the benchmark for analyzing cross-sectional data so the easy answer to this question is yes. As long as your data is in one time period this is perfectly fine.

Things get more complicated if your dependent variables is $\in (0,1)$ or if you have a large number of 0's in your dependent variable, for example, as there are better methods to deal with these kinds of data structures. Nonetheless, OLS still does an OK job with these problems although it is likely to be at least inefficient and at most biased and inconsistent.

Comment: "at most biased" is misleading. An inconsistent estimator is even worse as it does not even get it right when sample size tends to infinity. Many "decent" estimators are not unbiased.

Comment: You are absolutely right Christoph. I will correct this now to biased & inconsistent. I was referring to using OLS instead of a Probit\Logit or Tobit specification where the estimator is both biased and inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and surely will also run Logit, Probit and Tobit where those are applicable. Thanks again.